# how to active gupshup Opted user in WhastAppa Api

Tags: whatsapp, gupshup

I'm using Gupshup for WhatsApp business API
in that I can send a message to only active status is active, is there any API to active the opted user

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about sending a message to a user for the first time this article may be helpful.
The only way to message a user who hasn't messaged you in the last 24 hours is with a Message Template message.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages#cut-off-control